# JavaScript regex help

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use JavaScript split but I'm useless at regex so what i wanna do is take a text which is CSS like structure eg:

```
var str = "selector {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

.anything{
  margin: 5%;
}"; 

str.split(/regex goes here/);
```

Expected output

```
[
  0 = selector{width: 100px; height: 20px;},
  1 = .anything{margin: 5%;}
]
```

Hopefully it's not too confusing but please ask if in doubt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a split for this. Instead, use this regex to extract each rule:

```
([\s\S]*?{[\s\S]+?})
```

Very simple, but should work as long as there aren't { and } characters in the rules themselves (which I would expect would be rare). My regex ignores whitespace and newlines as long as the CSS is syntactically valid. I used `[\s\S]` in place of `.` because `.` doesn't match newlines.

In your case, to extract the rules it would be:

```
var myCSS = "CSS goes here";
var rules = myCSS.match(/([\s\S]*?{[\s\S]+?})/);
```

**EDIT:**

As per the askers request, I have modified my regex to ignore a selector such as: `a {}`. However, it will still catch `a { }`. I will try to find a solution for this but in the mean time you might just have to process each rule and remove empty ones.

Comment: thnx that does the job... so what if i decide to put a {} inside the rule would there be a way to ignore them ?

Comment: Ah, change the second `*` to a `+`. (See modified answer).

Comment: omg thnx I have been playing about with regex i still don't understand it to do the things I want it to do :) ... you have svaed me a life time because thats how long it would have taken me :)... im doing this script and i'd like to put ur credits in it, if you like post your details that want to go on the credits. thnx again

Comment: You are welcome! Thanks for the offer, but you don't need to accredit me :). Also, make sure you check each extracted rule that it's not empty. Try using: `myRule.test(/[\s\S]*{\s*}/);`. If that expression evaluates to true, the rule is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Regexps are not for parsing. You should write or find a CSS parser to do the job, but then that could make your code longer.

Try this:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = ".test { color: red; } .test2 { }";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(style);
var style = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
style.disabled = true;
var rules = style.cssRules;
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i ++) {
  list.push(rules[i].cssText + "");
}
list;
```

It asks the browser's CSS parser to do the job for you.

Due to the non-recursive nature of the CSS syntax, you can write a giant regexp to parse CSS.

Comment: nice one thanx :) they will now dissmiss extra "{}" withing the rule so for example  `select { value : {value} }` which is what i need to do.